# Base64 Image Download: Corrupted File

Tags: javascript, base64

I have a script that converts a canvas element into a base64 encoded image, sets it to the `href` of a link, and allows users to download it as a jpeg. I

In dev tools, I'm able to open the data URL and view the image just fine and I've verified that the `href` of the link is updated appropriately. However, the file that is downloaded is not able to be viewed. Attempting to open it in PhotoShop display the following error:

> Could not complete your request because a JPEG marker segment length
>   is too short (the file may be truncated or incomplete).

What could cause this?

Here is the function that sets the `href` value on click:

```
$(a).click(function() {
            var e = r.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            console.log(e); //Verify base64 encoded image which works correctly
            a.href = e;
            });
```

Comment: can you add working prototype?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @AndreiDvoynos Chrome v.47

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. I suspect your issue might be related to browser compatibility.

```
<h1>Copy graphic using toDataURL</h1>

  <div>
    <button id="copy">Copy canvas image to image element</button> <br />
    <canvas id="MyCanvas" width="400" height="400"  >This browser or document mode doesn't support canvas</canvas>
    <img id="MyPix" src="" width="400" height="400" />
    <a id="myAnchor" href="#" download>Some Link that should download whatever it's pointing to</a>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Create some graphics on the canvas.
    var canvas = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(5, 5, 300, 250);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.arc(150, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI, false);
      ctx.stroke();
   }

    // catch the click from the button and copy the graphic
    document.getElementById("copy").addEventListener("click", function () {
      var canvas1 = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
      var anchor = document.getElementById("myAnchor");
      if (canvas1.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");                // Get the context for the canvas.
        var myImage = canvas1.toDataURL("image/jpeg");      // Get the data as an image.
      }
      var imageElement = document.getElementById("MyPix");  // Get the img object.
      imageElement.src = myImage;                           // Set the src to data from the canvas.
      anchor.href = myImage;
    }, false);

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Href in the Click-Event is a bad idea, I think. Try setting it before clicking. See this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <a id="link" href="#">Download</a>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(150, 150);
        ctx.arc (100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
        context.closePath();
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.strokeStyle = '#444';
        context.stroke();

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("link").href = dataURL;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It will draw a circle and then directly set the HREF of the link. This will work fine.